# What would keep docker engine from upgrading to 1.11 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am managing around 20 Ubuntu 14.04 VMs running docker engine. These VMs have been around for several months and have been through a number of upgrades. Of the 20, all are running docker 1.11 except for 2, which refuse to upgrade from docker 1.10.3 for some reason. I've tried a number of things. Last night I went through these steps, which I really thought would do the trick:

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
sudo reboot
```

Unfortunately when the VMs came back up they were still running docker 1.10.3.

I started with the docker engine log (/var/log/upstart/docker.log) but there is no indication of a problem related to the upgrade.

I looked in the apt logs (/var/log/apt/term.log) for the 2 VMs that won't update, but there aren't any errors or messages indicating anything is wrong.

I also compared the repos (/etc/apt/sources.list) for a VM that did upgrade docker to 1.11 and one that didn't, and the sources are identical, which I would expect since I spun both VMs up with the same command line.

What could be preventing these VMs from upgrading to docker 1.11?
Where should I look to find the cause?

Comment: Probably should start with the apt logs at `/var/log/apt/term.log`. Credits to http://askubuntu.com/questions/425809/where-are-the-logs-for-apt-get.

Comment: Check the `/etc/apt/sources.list` for each machine to make sure you're pulling from the same repositories.

Comment: Have you done `apt-get install dist-upgrade`?